# Sequelize ERROR: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

My sequelize migration file being referenced in terminal:

```
Sequelize CLI [Node: 16.10.0, CLI: 6.2.0, ORM: 6.7.0]

Loaded configuration file "db\config.js".
Using environment "development".
== 20211021030720-create-customers: migrating =======

ERROR: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')
```

This is my model file:

```
const { Model, DataTypes, Sequelize } = require('sequelize');

const { USER_TABLE } = require('./user.model');

const CUSTOMER_TABLE = 'customers';

const CustomerSchema = {
  costomerId: {
    allowNull: false,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true,
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  },
  customerName: {
    allowNull: false,
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
  },
  customerLastname: {
    allowNull: false,
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
  },
  customerPhone: {
    allowNull: true,
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
  },
  createdAt: {
    allowNull: false,
    type: DataTypes.DATE,
    field: 'create_at',
    defaultValue: Sequelize.NOW,
  },
  userId: {
    field: 'user_id',
    allowNull: false,
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    references: {
      model: USER_TABLE,
      key: 'userId'
    },
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
    onDelete: 'SET NULL'
  }
}

class Customer extends Model {
  static associate(models) {
    this.belongsTo(models.User, {as: 'user'});
  }

  static config(sequelize) {
    return {
      sequelize,
      tableName: CUSTOMER_TABLE,
      modelName: 'Customer',
      timestamps: false
    }
  }
}

module.exports = { CUSTOMER_TABLE, CustomerSchema, Customer };
```

Other posts mention that it can be caused by an invalid property of DataTypes but I have already checked the code several times and I cannot find the problem.

If other information to help solve, please ask for it.

**EDIT**

I realized that I wrote `.addColumn` instead `.createTable`. Now everything is working properly.

```
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface) => {
    await queryInterface.createTable(CUSTOMER_TABLE, CustomerSchema);
  },
```